# Replace row values if sum is equal to zero in R

Tags: r, if-statement, replace, dplyr

I want to replace the values of columns by NA if the sum of their rows is equal to 0. Imagine the following columns:

```
a b 
0 0
1 5
2 8
3 7
0 0
5 8
```

I would like to replace these by:

```
a b 
NA NA
1 5
2 8
3 7
NA NA
5 8
```

I've been looking for answers on many pages but have not found any solution.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
df[ , 31:36][df[,31:36] == 0 ] <- NA    #With df being my dataframe and 31:36 the columns I want to apply the replacement too.
```

This replaces all the values equal to 0 by NA

I've also tried other alternatives using `rowSums()` but have not found a solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
a <- df[31:36,1]
b <- df[31:36,2]
c <- a
a[a+b==0] <- NA
b[c+b==0] <- NA
df[31:36,1] <- a
df[31:36,2] <- b
```

We have to create a temporary variable called `c`, otherwise when you are checking the second column, you will be adding `NA+0` which equals `NA` not `0`.

Answer (score 0):

An idiomatic way of doing this using `dplyr` would be:

```
library(dplyr)

tb <- tibble(
  a = c(0, 1:3, 0, 5), 
  b = c(0, 5, 8, 7, 0, 8)
)

tb <- tb %>%
  # creates a "rowsum" column storing the sum of columns 1:2 
  mutate(rowsum = rowSums(.[1:2])) %>% 
  # applies, to columns 1:2, a function that puts NA when the sum of the rows is 0
  mutate_at(1:2, funs(ifelse(rowsum == 0, NA, .))) %>%
  # removes rowsum
  select(-rowsum)
```

Of course you could replace 1:2 with 31:36 when applying the code to your actual table.

Comment: Perfect ! Sorry for the late answer. This helped me a lot! Must get familiar with using mutate.